# UPDATE multiple MySQL rows with different values

Tags: php, mysql

**Note**: I realize this may be confusing taking about tables and columns below so here is a simplified version of the two tables I mention:

**Table "categories" has columns**: id, type

**Table "entries" has columns**: id, categories, ...

I have a MySQL table named entries where one of the columns, named categories, is a string of pipe separated indices. For example, "|1|2|3|" might be a possible value and "|1|3|4|" could be another. The numbers represent indices of the table categories.

I'm writing an admin script that allows a new row to be inserted into the categories table and when doing this, the appropriate rows of the table entires should have the categories column updated. For example, if a newly inserted row of the categories table has index 5 then "5|" should be concatenated to each appropriate column categories of the entries table.

I realize that I could could use UPDATE per appropriate entries row when adding a new category but am wondering if there is a better way to go about this. In case this is not clear I know that this is an option but want to know if this can be made into one statement (pseudo-code):

```
foreach ($entriesToUpdate as $currEntry)
"UPDATE entires SET categories='".$currValue."|".$newIndex."' WHERE id=".$currId;
```

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't go ahead with that database design and regret it when you site gets big and your server goes down. That's not a good database schema at all

Comment: Regular SQL can't do what you want. You should have an additional table, where instead of |1|2|3|, in the additional table you would have 3 rows, each with one field which would be either 1, 2, or 3, and a second field which would have the ID of the row in the first table

Comment: @Jodes, I don't follow. Maybe it is worth pointing out that each entry may have 0 or more categories?

Comment: You have to add a table ENTIRES_CATEGORIES(entries_id, categories_id) because entries and categories are in a many to many relationship.

Comment: @kiks73 there's no reason to add a third field to the many-to-many table - just use the two fields as a composite primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with an expression-based update:

```
UPDATE entries SET categories=CONCAT(categories, "5|") WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,...)
```

(`5|` instead of `5|` from your example, since your examples seem to show that the existing value will start and end with `|`s already.)

---

That said, you'd probably be better off with a database schema that stores a mapping of entries to categories in a separate many-to-many table. For example:

**categories:**

```
id | type | ...
---------------
1    ...
2    ...
3    ...
```

**entries:**

```
id  | ...
---------
100   ...
101   ...
102   ...
```

**entries_to_categories:**

```
entry | category
----------------
100     1
100     2
101     3
```

Then you can use `JOINs` to retrieve the set of categories if desired, or check if something is in a category. In this case, entry `100` is in categories `1` and `2`, entry `101` is in category `3`, and entry `102` is in no categories.

Comment: This does seem like a good idea, I'll look into restructuring the tables / code. Thank you for posting the MySQL command as well